# Maximum number of annotations (MKAnnotation) that can be drawn on MKMapView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mkmapview, mkannotation

I want to add a number of annotations(arround 500) on a mapview but the maximum it seems to display is 100. If I go beyond 100, **viewForAnnotation** delegate method is not called. However it works perfectly for annotations below 100.

here is the code: (works only when count of **annotationArray** array is less than 101)

```
_allPoints = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSString* responseFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Datafile" ofType:@"txt"];
NSData *sampleData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:responseFile];  
if (sampleData) {  
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization 
                          JSONObjectWithData:sampleData

                          options:kNilOptions 
                          error:&error];

    NSArray* response = [json objectForKey:@"response"];
    for (NSDictionary *lineDict in response) {
        if ([[lineDict objectForKey:@"data"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
            SinglePoint *singlePoint = [[SinglePoint alloc] initWithDictionary:lineDict];
            [_allPoints addObject:singlePoint];
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Error");
        }
    }
}  


_mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
[_mapView setDelegate:self];
[self.view addSubview:_mapView];

NSMutableArray *annotationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i=0; i<[_allPoints count]; i++) {
    SinglePoint *singlePoint = [_allPoints objectAtIndex:i];
    NVPolylineAnnotation *annotation = [[NVPolylineAnnotation alloc] initWithPoint:singlePoint mapView:_mapView];
    [annotationArray addObject:annotation];
}
[_mapView addAnnotations:(NSArray *)annotationArray];

CLLocationCoordinate2D centerCoord = { 28.632747, 77.219982 };
[_mapView setCenterCoordinate:centerCoord zoomLevel:12 animated:NO];
```

The delegate method is:

**EDIT:** As per comments, started reusing the view but with no luck :(

```
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[NVPolylineAnnotation class]]) {
    static NSString *viewIdentifier = @"annotationView";
    NVPolylineAnnotationView *annotationView = (NVPolylineAnnotationView *) [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:viewIdentifier];
    if (annotationView == nil) {
        annotationView = [[NVPolylineAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:viewIdentifier mapView:_mapView];
    }
    return annotationView;
}
return nil;
```

I could not find any restriction in the documentation or anywhere else. Could it be memory issue?

Comment: What happens if you add the first object in `allPoints` 500 times to your `annotationArray`?

Comment: Is it possible to provide the source code for `NVPolylineAnnotation`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally was able to track down the problem. Solved it by setting the center of mapView first and then adding annotations later. I still dont know why 100 annotations were shown earlier (and why the no 100 only). Thank you all for your suggestions and time on this.

This is the code I changed:-

```
_mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
[_mapView setDelegate:self];
[self.view addSubview:_mapView];

CLLocationCoordinate2D centerCoord = { 28.632747, 77.219982 };
[_mapView setCenterCoordinate:centerCoord zoomLevel:12 animated:NO];

NSMutableArray *annotationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i=0; i<[_allPoints count]; i++) {
    SinglePoint *singlePoint = [_allPoints objectAtIndex:i];
    NVPolylineAnnotation *annotation = [[NVPolylineAnnotation alloc] initWithPoint:singlePoint mapView:_mapView];
    [annotationArray addObject:annotation];
}
[_mapView addAnnotations:(NSArray *)annotationArray];
```

Comment: Would it be possible to avoid the hardcoded latitude and longitude by constructing an `MKCoordinateRegion` that bounds all the annotation points, and then use [setRegion:animated:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKMapView/setRegion:animated:) to place the map at whatever position and zoom it needs?  (Do have a fallback if there are no points, or you'll trigger an exception.)

Answer (score 1):

The `MKMapView` has not Limit for `annotationViews`. But it gets quite laggy and unusable above a certain number of views (+1000).

I believe, that the reason for this is that you handle the `annotationView` management totally wrong. You shouldn't create a unique view for every single annotation, even if you are using ARC. Your rather should reuse every unused View like the cell of a `UITableView`.

There are a couple of good tutorials for this like [Introduction to MapKit on iOS - Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2847/introduction-to-mapkit-on-ios-tutorial).

If this won't resolve your problem, you should try to debug your annotation classes. (`NVPolylineAnnotation` and `NVPolylineAnnotationView`). Maybe there's something wrong.
Did you also checked your points array for equal coordinates?

Comment: Thanks @yinkou.. 1) I dont think the issue is with memory management because it happens exactly when there are 101 views. 2)I checked the points for equal co-ordinates but there are none. Even if some points are same, it should draw the remaining 100 points that I am able to see

Comment: You are right, nevertheless you should reuse the annotationViews since that is the recommended pattern. Can you post the code where you create and populate your _allPoints array?

Comment: shoudln't [_allPoints addObject:line]; be [_allPoints addObject:singlePoint];?
Anyway, i don't see an error anywhere. Maybe somewhere inside your singlePoint class the parsing of the dict goes wrong or the NVPolylineAnnotation returns coordinates outside of the map?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo.. I debugged and found the parsing to be correct. Also most of the coordinates are withing the map

Comment: @Shri: So according to your comment...if most of your annotations coordinates are within the map, does it stand to reason that most of your annotation views will be within the map?  In other words: most < 500?

Comment: Did you already try what T Reddy suggested? -  Edit: too slow. ;)

Comment: Yes.. most < 100.. When i give 100 co-ordinates it shows on the map.. when i add just one more, nothing is shown. I am quite sure the one i am adding is correct co-ordinate.

Comment: @Shri: So if you agree with me that if only 100 annotations are visible on the map, then you'll only see 100 annotation views, what exactly is your question/problem?  As stated in my answer, MapKit will not create a view just because you added an annotation to the map.  That annotation coordinates must intersect with the map's visible portion.

Comment: @TReddy.. My question is I am not able to see ANY annotation on the map when I give 101 annotations. When I remove any one random annotation to make it 100, I am able to see all of them.

Comment: Thats a very, very weird and unusual problem. Did you try it on different devices, different iOS versions?

Comment: @Shri: I apologize for not understanding the original question.  I was reading it to say the first 100 annotations were visible but afterwards none showed up.

Comment: @yinkou.. I tried on the iPhone simulator, iPad Simulator, iPhone running iOS 4.3... same behavior on all.. I am trying to implement the same using overlays now.

Comment: @yinkou.. As per your comments I tried reusing the views but still the issue is happening. Modified the code above.

Comment: After the if statement you should set the annotation of your annotationView to the new one. Please let me know when you have fixed your problem, i'm very curious about this.

Answer (score 0):

You can add as many annotations as you like.  However, the views for each annotation will not be created until that annotation's `coordinate` property intersects with the visible portion of your map view.  MapKit will not create a view just because you added an annotation to the map.

Comment: In this case, it does not draw only when the views number goes above 100. If I supply 101 views, the first 100 views are still the earlier views that were being showned and in the visible portion. But As soon as go gor 101 views, nothing is shown. Even the delegate is not called.